# Postgres: Always use default column value, even if insertion is attempted

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm creating a user table using postgres. My table is the following...

```
create table if not exists "user" (
    user_id bigserial primary key,
    username varchar(20) not null,
    "password" varchar(100) not null,
    created_datetime timestamp default (now() at time zone 'utc')
);
```

Is it possible for create_datetime to only use the default column, even if an insert script attempts to inserts a timestamp into created_datetime? Preferably postgres would even thrown an error if an insert script tries to insert a timestamp into the create_datetime column.

Answer (score 2):

Create a trigger that will fill that column disregarding any value provided in `INSERT`:

```
create or replace function t_user_created_datetime() returns trigger as $$
begin
  new.created_datetime := now() at time zone 'utc';
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger t_user_created_datetime
  before insert on "user"
  for each row execute procedure t_user_created_datetime();
```

Check:

```
test=# insert into "user"(user_id, username, "password", created_datetime) values(1, 'test', 'test', '1900-01-01'::timestamp);
INSERT 0 1
test=# select * from "user";
 user_id | username | password |      created_datetime
---------+----------+----------+----------------------------
       1 | test     | test     | 2017-07-27 18:21:24.501701
(1 row)
```

With such trigger, you *can* remove `default (now() at time zone 'utc')` from the table's definition, because it becomes useless.

If you do want to see an error when the column's value is explicitly set in `INSERT`, then change the trigger function to something like this:

```
create or replace function t_user_created_datetime() returns trigger as $$
begin
  if new.created_datetime is not null then
    raise exception 'It is forbidden to explicitly set "created_datetime" during INSERT to "user" table.';
  end if;
  new.created_datetime := now() at time zone 'utc';
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

In this case, the column `created_datetime` *must not* have `default` 
 because otherwise you'll see that error always.

P.S. I stronly recommend consider using `timestamptz` – it is also 8 bytes, like `timestamp`, but case save a lot of efforts if you need (or will need in the future) to deal with multiple time zones.

Comment: Thanks for the timestamptz suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

[`Revoke`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html) the insert and update privileges on the table from all the roles:

```
revoke insert, update
on table "user"
from public, application_role
cascade
```

Then `grant` the insert and update privileges to the application role on the other columns only:

```
grant 
    insert (user_id, username, "password"),
    update (username, "password")
on table "user"
to application_role
```

Only the table owner will be able to insert and update on the `created_datetime`  column.

Comment: "_On the other hand, if a role has been granted privileges on a table, then revoking the same privileges from individual columns will have no effect._" From [there](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-revoke.html). So it should be `revoke insert, update on ...;` and then `grant insert(...), update(...) on ...;`

Comment: @Abelisto Ok I think I fixed it.

Comment: Except the unclear error message (something like "permission denied on relation user") it is probably the most efficient and flexible solution. PS: why not just `grant insert(user_id, user_name, password), update(....`?

Answer (score 1):

To make the set of answers complete. Use [rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules.html).

First we will create the service function to be able to raise exceptions from SQL statements:

```
create or replace function public.fn_raise(msg text, cond boolean = true)
  returns bool
  immutable
  language plpgsql
as $$ 
begin
  if cond then
    raise exception '%', msg;
  end if;
  return false;
end $$;
```

Next lets create the test table:

```
create table t(i int, d timestamptz not null default current_timestamp);
```

And, finally, rule:

```
create or replace rule rul_t_insert as on insert to t
where new.d <> current_timestamp
do also
  select fn_raise(format('Can not insert %s into table t', new.d), new.d <> current_timestamp);
```

Lets test it:

```
postgres=# insert into t(i) values(1) returning *;
┌───┬───────────────────────────────┐
│ i │               d               │
╞═══╪═══════════════════════════════╡
│ 1 │ 2017-07-28 12:31:37.255392+03 │
└───┴───────────────────────────────┘

postgres=# insert into t(i,d) values(1,null) returning *;
ERROR:  null value in column "d" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null).

postgres=# insert into t(i,d) values(2,'2000-10-10') returning *;
ERROR:  Can not insert 2000-10-10 00:00:00+03 into table t
```

I the question mentioned only `insert` but if you also want to block updates of this field, you could to create another rule:

```
create or replace rule rul_t_update as on update to t
where new.d <> old.d
do also
  select fn_raise(format('Can not change t.d to %s', new.d), new.d <> old.d);
```

Test:

```
postgres=# update t set i = 3 where i = 1 returning *;
┌───┬───────────────────────────────┐
│ i │               d               │
╞═══╪═══════════════════════════════╡
│ 3 │ 2017-07-28 12:31:37.255392+03 │
└───┴───────────────────────────────┘

postgres=# update t set i = 4, d = current_timestamp where i = 3 returning *;
ERROR:  Can not change t.d to 2017-07-28 12:39:18.963852+03
```